# Formula expansion symbol / /

Tags: math-mode

I need to expand formula in LaTeX using `/ /`  symbols, like this:

Current version:

[image]

Needed version:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Try `\[ \left/ \begin{array}{l} V(p)= \\ F(p)= \end{array} \right/ \]`

Comment: @aioobe: care to turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Converting a comment to an answer]

Try

```
\[ \left/ \begin{array}{l} V(p)= \\ F(p)= \end{array} \right/ \]
```